# How can I create a pie chart for a column containing frequencies of responses of "Not all familiar to Extremely familiar" ratings

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data set where one of the columns contains frequencies of responses of "Not all familiar, slightly familiar, Moderately familiar, very familiar, and Extremely familiar" ratings.

The column of interest in the dataset is column 15 (Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept): and the dataset can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TLw-UG8WOlFQ3dCn4Kmdok6I2rJL3M31oYb4_a_AxjU/edit?usp=sharing

I have modified the rating to get the count and percentages as follows

```
F_ogd_data_new <- ogd_data_new %>%
   dplyr::select(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept) %>%
   dplyr::group_by(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(Frequency = n()) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(Percent = round(Frequency/sum(Frequency)*100, 1)) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept = factor(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept, 
                            levels = 1:5,
                            labels = c("Not at all familiar",
                                       "Slightly familiar", 
                                       "Moderately familiar", 
                                       "Very familiar", 
                                       "Extremely familiar")))"
```

I get an error on running this line

```
  dplyr::mutate(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept = factor(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept, 
                            levels = 1:5,
                            labels = c("Not at all familiar",
                                       "Slightly familiar", 
                                       "Moderately familiar", 
                                       "Very familiar", 
                                       "Extremely familiar")))"
```

It returns an output as follows:

[image: Table_output]

How can I rectify the error and proceed to plotting a pie-chart using ggplot?

I expect a piechart like this one:

[image: _Expected_Piechart]

Comment: Check `unique(ogd_data_new$Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept)` and see what that column looks like. You don't have to set the levels nor the labels, just run `Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept = factor(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept)` in the `mutate`. Vote to close as simple typo.

Comment: I have run the line. It arranges it in alphabetical order: "Extremely familiar, moderately familiar, not at all familiar, slightly familiar, very familiar" . I was expecting to have "Not at all familiar, slightly familiar, moderately familiar, very familiar and extremely familiar" How can I achieve this? @RuiBarradas

Comment: @RuiBarradas With this, please guide me on how I can create the pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.
The problem was in coercing to factor and changing the values (levels). The question's `labels` are the wanted `levels` in the wanted order.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

ogd_data_new %>%
  select(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept) %>%
  count(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept) %>%
  mutate(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept = factor(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept, 
                                                 levels = c("Not at all familiar",
                                                            "Slightly familiar", 
                                                            "Moderately familiar", 
                                                            "Very familiar", 
                                                            "Extremely familiar"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n, fill = Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            color = "white", size = 5) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

It is not clear in the question if the plot's labels are counts or percentages. Here is a plot labelled with percentages.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

ogd_data_new %>%
  select(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept) %>%
  count(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept) %>%
  mutate(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept = factor(Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept, 
                                                 levels = c("Not at all familiar",
                                                            "Slightly familiar", 
                                                            "Moderately familiar", 
                                                            "Very familiar", 
                                                            "Extremely familiar")),
         Prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = n, fill = Q5_Know_Familirity_ogd_Concept)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Prop)), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            color = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>